# Cannot get Arch Linux to boot in VirtualBox 5.0 using UEFI

Tags: archlinux

I have been trying to setup Arch Linux on VirtualBox5.  After installing, I can run `reboot` command and the system will reboot fine.  If I shut the system down, to get the system to reboot, I have to hit `F12` then choose `Boot Manager` then choose `EFI Hard Drive`, and then it will boot from the ESP partition.  Below is my hard drive printout:

[image: partitions]

Also below is the location of the BOOTX64.EFI

[image]

I use the following script to install it:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sittim/configs/master/arch_i

I have also posted this question to here:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211475.

Here is the sequence of startup when F12 is pressed:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sittim/configs/master/Arch-2016-04-19T03-26-11-731417000Z.webm

Answer (score 0):

Changing boot order in Virtual Box did not work for me.  Had to eject the ISO and then it worked fine.